# How to add a Dynamic Range Filter for multi-value property?

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkit

The `DynamicRangeFilter` in Searchkit is a nice and easy solution to e.g. filter years. You would just save a year field in Elasticsearch and use the filter:

```
<DynamicRangeFilter
    field="year"
    id="year"
    title="Year"
/>
```

So far I didn't find out how it could be used to filter a multi-value property, e.g. a range of years. Imagine you have a duration property with a `start` and `end`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "title": "Foo",
    "duration": {
      "start": 2013,
      "end": 2016
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 234,
    "title": "Bar",
    "duration": {
      "start": 2015,
      "end": 2015
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 345,
    "title": "Baz",
    "duration": {
      "start": 2017,
      "end": 2020
    }
  }
]
```

Now, the filter should respect the duration and display all items within range. I'm not sure if and how [fieldOptions](http://docs.searchkit.co/stable/core/FieldOptions.html) could be used to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this if you use date filter component for Searchkit like follows:

**A calendar-style date filter component for Searchkit**

> This Searchkit filter lets users filter start-end date ranges based on
>   a chosen start time and an optional end time.
>
> See **[demo directory](https://github.com/MarttiR/searchkit-datefilter/tree/master/demo)** for a working example.
>
> [image]
>
> The Searchkit components needed for date range filtering were
>   originally published **[here](https://github.com/City-of-Turku/kada-elastic-events)** under the MIT license.
>
> **Install**
>
> ```
> npm install --save-dev searchkit-datefilter
> ```
>
> **Example**
>
> ```js
> import { SearchkitComponent } from "searchkit";
> import { DateRangeFilter, DateRangeCalendar } from "searchkit-datefilter"
>
> class App extends SearchkitComponent
> {
>     render()
>     {
>         <div>
>             <DateRangeFilter
>                 id="event_date"
>                 title="Date range"
>                 fromDateField="event_date.from"
>                 toDateField="event_date.to"
>                 calendarComponent={DateRangeCalendar}
>                 fieldOptions={{
>                     type: 'embedded',
>                     options: {
>                         path: 'event_date'
>                     }
>                 }}
>             />
>         </div>
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **Properties**
>
> - `fromDateField` *(ESField)*: **Required**. An elasticsearch date field to use as the beginning.
> - `toDateField` *(ESField)*: **Required**. An elasticsearch date field to use as the end.
> - `id` *(string)*: **Required**. id of component. Must be unique. Used as key for url serialisation
> - `title` *(string)*: **Required**. Title used for component and for selected filters component
> - `calendarComponent` (ReactComponent): Calendar component to use when rendering
>
>   - Compatible with `DateRangeCalendar`
>   - Defaults to `DateRangeFilterInput` which just shows two date math input fields
> - `fieldOptions` *({type:"embedded|nested|children", options:Object})* Configures the type field that is stored in ElasticSearch, can be
>     embedded or nested or children
>
>   - type:nested requires options.path provided
>   - type:children requires options.childType provided
>   - see [Field Options](http://docs.searchkit.co/stable/core/FieldOptions.html) in Searchkit documentation
> - `rangeFormatter` *((count:number)=> string|number)* A formatter function used to convert numbers into more readable display values.
>     E.g. long number formatting or prefixing currencies.`
>
> > The full description you can find in date filter code repositories: **[here](https://github.com/MarttiR/searchkit-datefilter)** and **[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/searchkit-datefilter)**.

The full example from the part of code above you can find **[here](https://github.com/MarttiR/searchkit-datefilter/blob/master/demo/app/index.tsx)**.

*I hope it helps you. Good luck!*